# In the proof of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}(2x-1) = 1$, why do we choose $\delta=\epsilon/2$?

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, epsilon-delta

First of all, I didn't understand why mathematicians call it a proof?is it really a proof?
What are we trying to prove?
It's kind of like we're putting some numbers and the equality just works.
Consider this limit : $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}{2x-1} = 1$$
So I try to do the epsilon delta steps,
 $$0<|x-1|<\delta$$ 
 $$|2x-1-1|=|2x-2|= 2|x-1|<\epsilon$$
$$|x-1|< \frac {\epsilon}{2}$$

Now we say $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{2}$ , but why? I don't understand **why we make them equal?**

Comment: You are "trying to prove" that $\lim_{x\to 1} 2x-1 = 1$. $\epsilon-\delta$ is the definition of limit, so it is kind of necessary.

Comment: Make "them" equal? What does "them" refer to? Here, if $\epsilon>0$ you can choose any $0<\delta\leq \frac{\epsilon}2$. In any even, $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are not equal.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If they're not equal, why do we say $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{2}$?Why is this proof necessary?Why?

Comment: I'd argue that you aren't really done. While you have a value for $\delta$, there is still some writing to demonstrate that the first equation is correct and not someone's imagination which may or may not be right.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? It seems like a valid question about the meaning of a limit and how to prove a limit using the $\delta-\epsilon$ method.

Comment: This closure is ridiculous. The OP showed an entire proof, but had questions about what it is proving. What more context could you ask for? This is definitely not a PSQ. If it is the level of the question that is bothering people, let me quote from the top of our Help page: "Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math at **any level** and professionals in related fields" (emphasis added).

Comment: You can contrast this e.g. with attempting to find such a $\delta$ given $\epsilon =\frac12$ say, to test $\lim_{x \to 1}$ for the function $f=2x-1$ for $x\ge 1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: My question was, what is "they" or "them." "They are equal" is vague. You don't need to find more than one $\delta$, given $\epsilon,$ so we usually find a $\delta$ that works well. Delta doesn't have to equal $\epsilon/2$ - it could be any smaller positive value, too. But we need to prove that some such $\delta$ exists, and we do so by picking a value.

Answer (score 2):

We're basically saying that, provided we make $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then that guarantees $f(x)$ will be within $\epsilon$ units of the limit.  We could just as easily say $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, but that would be extraneous, because we already have the condition that $|x - 1| < \delta$. We could also just as easily say $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, which would certainly also guarantee $f(x)$ is close enough to the limit.  It's just that we **know** setting $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ will imply that we can get close enough to the limit. Using $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is better, because it is the greatest distance $x$ can be from $1$ while still guaranteeing $f(x)$ will be within $\epsilon$ of the limit.

So, if $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then $$0 < |x - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \implies |2x -1 -1| < \epsilon$$ which is what we're trying to show.

This is necessary, because it lets us know that we can get $f(x)$ as close to the limit as we want, provided $x$ is within half of the distance between $f(x)$ and the limit.  It therefore shows that the limit exists, because we **can** get as close as we want to it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of saying
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b\tag{1}
$$
is for all $\epsilon\gt0$, there is a $\delta\gt0$ so that for all $x$ such that $|x-a|\le\delta$, we have $|f(x)-b|\le\epsilon$.

To prove that this latter statement is true, we choose an *arbitrary* $\epsilon\gt0$, then try to find a $\delta$ (based on our choice of $\epsilon$) that satisfies
$$
|x-a|\le\delta\implies|f(x)-b|\le\epsilon\tag{2}
$$
In the case of $f(x)=2x-1$, and $a=1$ and $b=1$, for a given $\epsilon\gt0$, $\delta=\epsilon/2$ is a sufficiently small $\delta$ to satisfy $(2)$.